# Get string between quotes

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string that includes either double or single quotation. What I need to do is to echo everything between quotation:

```
 $str = "'abc de', xye, jhy, jjou";
 $str2 = "\"abc de\", xye, jhy, jjou";
```

I do not mind using Regular Expression(preg_match), or any other php built in function.

Please advice.

Regards,

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: i do not have much knowledge about regular expression. I could have tried other function but whatever I know needs to know string position. in this case quotation won't always be at first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$str = "'abc de', xye, \"jhy\", blah blah 'bob' \"gfofgok\", jjou";
preg_match_all('/".*?"|\'.*?\'/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

This returns:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( 
      [0] => 'abc de' 
      [1] => "jhy" 
      [2] => 'bob' 
      [3] => "gfofgok" 
   )
)
```

Explanation of regex:

```
"   -> Match a double quote
.*  -> Match zero or more of any character
?"  -> Match as a non-greedy match until the next double quote
|   -> or
\'  -> Match a single quote
.*  -> Match zero or more of any character
?\' -> Match as non-greedy match until the next single quote.
```

So `$matches[0]` is an array that contains all strings that exist inside single or double quotes.

Comment: Why not combine them into one, such as `(['"])(.*?)\1`?

Comment: yes, I was hoping to get something combined. As this will go in foreach loop.

Comment: works like a charm. thank you. Its time for me to learn RE. :)

Comment: @HassanZ Just keep at it; you'll eventually get it. :)

Answer (score 1):

regex are not that complicated even if they look scary at start have a look on a tutorial or on it's documentation it will clear a lot

as per your problem have a look on this and try to understand it before you use it

```
 $str = "'abc de', xye, jhy, jjou";
 $str2 = "\"abc de\", xye, jhy, jjou";
$match = $match2 = array();
preg_match("/'(.+)'/", $str, $match);
preg_match("/\"(.+)\"/", $str2, $match2);
print_r($match);
print_r($match2);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this situation you can use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) built in function:

```
function getBetween($string){
  //explode the string
    $exploded=explode("'",$string);
  //print using foreach loop or in any way you want
    foreach($exploded as $explode){
      echo $explode.'<br/>';
    } 
}
```

Comment: This does not cover the case with double-quotes. Also the function is supposed to print only the strings between quotes.